# bottle: can not import route

Tags: virtualenv, bottle, python-3.2

I am getting the following error:

```
(virtualenv)[chirdeep@fedora-desktop ~]$ python programs/python/myrestapi.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "programs/python/myrestapi.py", line 2, in <module>
import bottle
 File "/home/chirdeep/programs/python/bottle.py", line 1, in <module>
 from bottle import route, run
 ImportError: cannot import name route
```

I have got python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3. (virtualenv) is pointing to python3 and I have installed bottle in here and its available under site-packges..

I can import bottle when I am under python console after activating the environment.

```
(virtualenv)[chirdeep@fedora-desktop ~]$ python
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 26 2012, 22:03:19) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bottle
>>>
```

Any help will be much appreciated, driving me mad.

Thanks

Comment: Is `virtualenv` giving you any advantages? Just put the `bottle` file in your project directory and be happy.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought about. Thats an alternative but still dont understand why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 16):

Your own Python file is called `bottle.py`:

```
File "/home/chirdeep/programs/python/bottle.py", line 1, in <module>
```

So the *real* `bottle.py` is shadowed by your own file. Since your own file does *not* contain `route` and `run`, this fails:

```
from bottle import route, run
```

Rename your own file, perhaps `mybottle.py`.

Comment: ...and don't forget to delete the `bottle.pyc` file if exists.

Comment: @GregD That was my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the issue has to do with the collision of your program's namespace with bottle. I.e.: Python is trying to import route from /home/chirdeep/programs/python/bottle.py rather than the bottle.py in site-packages.

Try renaming your program file.